# Min max buttons not displayed

Tags: gnome, gsettings

What can be the cause for min max buttons not getting displayed for some windows in a jave ui application.

I have runned command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

but no result.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

returns

```
':minimize,maximize,close'
```

It means that the preferences were already activated or i have to do a reload or something similar?

What check should i execute in order to see that everything is well setup related with OS settings.

I'm running on gnome 2.16.